# How can I wrap a request interceptor in a custom hook when using an Axios instance?

Tags: reactjs

I have a project structure as follows:

```
/services
   api.config.ts
   user.services.ts
```

In `api.config.ts`, I have defined an Axios instance using apisauce:

```
import { API_BASE_URL } from '@/lib/env';
import { create } from 'apisauce';

export const api = create({
  baseURL: API_BASE_URL
});
```

In `user.services.ts`, I have services for operations like registration and login.

Given the rules for React hooks:

1. They must be used within a React component.
2. They should be called at the top level, not inside loops, conditions, or nested functions.
3. Their names should be prefixed with use.

Considering that `api.config` and `user.services` don't meet the first and second rule, how can I implement a request interceptor using a custom hook?

I thought about exporting the Axios instance from api.config, wrapping it in a custom hook, and then applying the desired behavior. However, this approach falls short because I can't call this custom hook, let's say `useAxios`, inside the services.

How can I achieve this? Does anyone have suggestions on how to proceed?

Comment: Here's one thing I've tried - invert the services' dependencies on the "request maker" (fetch-y, in my case, but that's not required), then have a useService hook to provide a service with the context-aware (in this case for React Router) request maker injected: https://github.com/CodeYourFuture/tech-products-demo/blob/3a0f07f042436ffe03c7351cdd1d0ac3b5118920/client/src/services/index.js#L8-L19